# Maven shade plugin conflict resolution for overlapping classes and resources

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

In my maven project there are multiple shaded jars. Few of them have same dependency like jackson but without doing relocation. Whenever i try to create a fat jar of my project using maven shade plugin it complains like below

```
[WARNING] common-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.6.3.jar define 53 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.DecimalUtils
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module$1
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule$1
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.PackageVersion
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.DurationDeserializer
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer
[WARNING]   - 43 more...
```

Had common-client relocated jackson we would not have face any issue.

But with the current state, how will maven decide which classes should be picked between common-client's jackson classes vs jackson-datetype's jackson class? we are facing issue where some times the fat jar is running successfully but at times failing because of some method not being present. IS possible to make the selection deterministic?

Comment: The first question would be how does your pom file look like and what kind of dependencies have you defined and how is your common-client being created ...

Comment: common-client is a shaded jar, having dependency on jackson-datatype-jsr. my pom file has a dependency on common-client

Comment: That's what I expected.. a shaded using to create another shaded jar is usually a problem..you should define the dependencies of the original and generate that...

Comment: but at times that is not in our control. hence we are stuck.

Comment: The general issue with shaded jars is that you can't control anymore dependencies/transitives etc. (best would be to inform the others of the shaded jar to change to a usual jar with pom and dependencies) So the only solution is to exclude the overlapping parts...

Comment: The conflict resolution should be predictable is all I am asking.

Comment: What kind of conflict resolution? The issue is simply the shaded jar contains classes etc. and you have defined dependencies which contain the same classes..that means you have to exclude those overlapping classes... via configuration in maven-shade-plugin....